# Detect if an aggregate is null in a SQL case conditional statement

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables:

- **entities:** list of entities, some of them can participate to an event;
- **events:** list of the events;
- **participations:** list of participations

Here are the structures:

```
ENTITIES
id  |  name
```

```
EVENTS
id  |  name | date_start | date_end
```

```
PARTICIPATIONS
id  |  id_event  | id_participation | type
```

I'd like to get all the entities, with in the column "`events`" the array of all the events. Here is what gives me a good result:

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.name,
    array_agg(
        json_build_object(
            'id', evts.id,
            'name', evts.name,
            'date_start', evts.date_start,
            'date_end', evts.date_end
        )
    ) as events
FROM g.entities e
LEFT JOIN public.events_participations p
ON (
    p.id_participation::integer = e.id
    AND type ='entity'
    )
LEFT JOIN public.events evts
ON evts.id = p.id_event
WHERE e.id = 22
GROUP BY p.id_participation, e.id
```

BUT (and there is a but otherwise I wouldn't write here) when an entity doesn't participate in any event, I have this in the column:

```
{"{\"id\" : null, \"name\" : null, \"date_start\" : null, \"date_end\" : null}"}
```

I thought I could get a "`NULL`" because of the `LEFT JOIN`.

I tried to use "`CASE`" to detect when there are no event, but it doesn't seem to be the solution. How could I get the expected result and get an array only if there is at least one event and `NULL` otherwise?

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
WITH list_events AS (
    SELECT
        e.id,
        json_build_object(
            'id', evts.id,
            'name', evts.name,
            'date_start', evts.date_start,
            'date_end', evts.date_end
        ) as events
    FROM g.entities e
    LEFT JOIN public.events_participations p
    ON (
        p.id_participation::integer = e.id
        AND type ='entity'
        )
    JOIN public.events evts
    ON evts.id = p.id_event
    WHERE e.id = 1
)

SELECT
    e.id,
    e.nom,
    array_agg(
        l.*
    ) as events
FROM g.entities e
LEFT JOIN list_events l
ON e.id = l.id
WHERE e.id = 1
GROUP BY e.id
```

But instead of having "NULL" I have en empty column of type "record[]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was almost there:

```
WITH list_events AS (
    SELECT
        e.id,
        json_build_object(
            'id', evts.id,
            'name', evts.name,
            'date_start', evts.date_start,
            'date_end', evts.date_end
        ) as events
    FROM g.entities e
    LEFT JOIN public.events_participations p
    ON (
        p.id_participation::integer = e.id
        AND type ='entity'
        )
    JOIN public.events evts
    ON evts.id = p.id_event
    WHERE e.id = 1
)

SELECT
    e.id,
    e.nom,
    array_agg(
        l.events
    ) as events
FROM g.entities e
LEFT JOIN list_events l
ON e.id = l.id
WHERE e.id = 1
GROUP BY e.id
```